# Values changing after adding object pointer to vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct

Let's say I have a struct "A" with four members there. The four members are named:

- one
- two
- three
- four

I also have a struct "B" with five members there. Four of the five members come from struct A.
Then I have a vector with struct B pointers. I add every created struct B to this vector.

This looks like this:

```
std :: vector <B *> vec;
for (A& a : input.buffer())
{
   B b =
   {
      a.one, a.two, a.three, a.four, random value
   };
   vec.push_back (& ​​b);
}
function_which_needs_a_const_pointer_to_the_first_element_and_size_of_vector      (vec.front (), vec.size ());
```

Now I have used a number of std :: cout at different points in the code.
I print the following values:

```
a.one = 1304505
b.one (just before the push_back) = 1304505
vec [0] -> one (after the push_back) = 24050434
```

So as you can see I am troubled by values ​​that change after adding to the vector, as a result of which the rest of the code can no longer function correctly.
Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this? I probably do something stupid.

I tried google now for two days, but nothing seemed to help.

Thanks to some of your comments I know now that there are dangling pointers. If I make it a vector of shared pointers instead of raw pointers, I will have a invalid conversion from shared pointer to const raw pointer error. 
So now, we know the issue. But what is the best way to fix it? Because I am not allowed to touch that const raw pointer in that function.

Before you all press the down vote button; None of you is still able to give me the correct solution.

Comment: Your vector contains dangling pointers after the loop.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. `for (each struct A in container)` is not valid code. We cannot find the bug in code you do not show us

Comment: if you fill a vector like that, this is a perfectly clear indication that your vector should contain objects not pointers

Comment: It seems like you are creating copies of A in B, which is a local variable. When you exit the code, the variable B b is out of scope so its contents are no longer valid.

Comment: The problem is that your objects don't exist when you try to use them. You should never store a pointer you acquire with `&` for later use. Read about `new` in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: @molbdnilo I am not allowed to use new.

Comment: What is it with all these arbitrary restrictions that prevent proper learning? smh

Comment: @TrebledJ well, they told me that they would prefer not to. But I just did, because it was the only solution and now they accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate cause of the problem is that your objects don't exist when you try to use them.
You should never store a pointer you acquire with `&` for later use.

The more fundamental source of the problem is that you have misunderstood the exercise.

The function you're not allowed to modify wants a pointer to the vector's first element, but `vec.front()` is not a pointer to the vector's first element - it *is* the vector's first element.
 (This element happens to be a pointer, but it's not a pointer to the beginning of the vector).

You can get pointer to `vec`'s first element with `&vec[0]` or `vec.data()` or `&vec.front()`.

This is what you should pass to the function, and your vector's type should be `vector<B>`.

That is,

```
std::vector<B> vec;
for (A& a: input.buffer())
{
   B b ={ a.one, a.two, a.three, a.four, random value };
   vec.push_back(​b);
}
function_with_long_name(vec.data(), vec.size());
```

Comment: My bad, sorry. I meant the first element. 
I can not copy the data, otherwise I will have to copy thousands of times.

Comment: @Gigitex Why do you think you would need to copy anything?

Comment: Well you said vector<B> instead of vector<B*> doesn't that mean that I will copy the struct in to that vector instead of just passing the pointer?

Comment: @Gigitex Yes, but you're going to need to create that many objects anyway. You can use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` if you really have performance problems, but you won't have a problem unless `B` is very expensive to copy. (Thousands is almost nothing on a modern computer.)

Answer (score 0):

When you `vec.push_back (& ​​b);`, you are pushing a pointer to an object that is about to cease to exist. There isn't a `B` to point to when you `vec[0]->one`

Comment: Thanks, now I now the issue. Now need to find a solution hehe.

Answer (score 0):

You pass an address of local variable that becomes unavailable when going out of scope, that's why your vector will contain pointers to memory with no data available.

Comment: What would be a proper solution then?

Answer (score -1):

See comments in code.

```
std :: vector <B > vec; // just copy them all
for (A& a : input.buffer())
{
   B b =
   {
      a.one, a.two, a.three, a.four, random value
   };
   vec.push_back (​​b); //not passing by reference anymore, just copy.
}
function_which_needs_a_const_pointer_to_the_first_element_and_size_of_vector      (&vec.front (), vec.size ()); // Passing the reference of vec->front for the first element of the vector.
```

Comment: You can remove the `unique_ptr` - it does not affect any lifetimes and is not what solves the problem. The "not storing pointers in the vector" and "actually passing a pointer to the first element" are what solves the problem.

Comment: Seems to work as well @molbdnilo I will edit it, thanks.